# HTML5 video not autoplaying onload - WordPress plugin

Tags: mediaelement.js

I just installed/activated the WP plugin yet the video does not begin to play when 'Play' is selected. Any insight as to why this and how to correct?

Thank you kindly!

Ben

Comment: On Apple mobile devices like iPad and iPhone auto play is completely disabled and can not be changed. Does the same happen on desktop browsers? also is this specific to a particular browser?